# c# DB Column Values

Tags: c#, mysql, database, select

```
     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=db4free.net;user=*;password=*;database=*;");
    MySqlCommand xcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT x FROM members WHERE id='" + Login.idd + "';");
      xcmd.Connection = con;
        xint.Connection = con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        xcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int xx = (int)xcmd.ExecuteScalar();
        xcmd.Connection.Close();;
        xcmd.Dispose();
        x = xx;
        con.Close();
        if (x == 2)
        {
            button6.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.logo;
        }
```

I want the program to read the value of X from the database, add it in a variable and then if it is equal to 2 to show the logo...

Comment: Apart from your SQL Injection issue with your string concatenation, what exactly is the issue? You don't need the `DataTable` or the `ExecuteNoneQuery` lines either.

Comment: and `xInt.Connection` is a total mistery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, you have some bits you don't need; for example, the DataTable, the xint command, and the ExecuteNonQuery (which is for doing stuff which only updates/inserts/deletes from the database, for example, and doesn't return results)

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=db4free.net;user=*;password=*;database=*;"))
{
    using(MySqlCommand xcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT x FROM members WHERE id=@loginid;"))
    {
        xcmd.connection = con;
        xcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginid", Login.idd);
        con.Open();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(xcmd.ExecuteScalar());
        //Do something with x
        if(x == 2)
        {
            button6.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.logo;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are going to be doing this style of data access, I would recommend [parameterizing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) your query, and using the '[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)' statement.

The first will help prevent SQL Injection attacks, while the second will ensure non-managed resources are disposed of when you leave the scope of the various blocks.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your code, does it enter the `x == 2` block? What kind of application are you using? Windows Forms, ASP.Net, WPF?

Comment: What value is x then? If you run the same query directly against the database, from say MySql Workbench, then what value do you get back?

Comment: Do you get 0 if you query the database directly?

Comment: i dunno exactly how to query the db directly but yeah..in db the x is 0 because it's a command that updates the X in the program and when i click on a button x becomes 2 and when i click another button it becoms 0 again..

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecuteScalar`, it's much more straight forward:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=db4free.net;user=*;password=*;database=*;");
MySqlCommand xcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT x FROM members WHERE id='" + Login.idd + "';", con);

con.Open();
var x = (int)xcmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
if (x == 2)
{
    button6.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.logo;
}
```

further, please take note to the answer provided by **dash**. I generally add that to my answers, and was in the process, but saw his addition.

And a note about setting a `BackgroundImage` -you need to work with the `Layout` and `Size`. The following code is from MSDN:

```
// Specify the layout style of the background image. Tile is the default.
button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;

// Make the button the same size as the image.
button1.Size = button1.BackgroundImage.Size;
```

those settings above may not be right based on your image.

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: @VlasiuRobert, please see my edit. I added a cast to `(int)` to allow that statement to succeed.